# Can't Login To App With Heroku. Works Locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Yet Another Heroku Problem....

When working in development mode, users can login to the app no problem.

In Production Mode on Heroku, this is not the case - a POST request to /api/login returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

In Production Mode, my app seems to be connected to the correct database as /api/users returns the full list of registered users.

Heroku just seems to be throwing a 500 error just for the hell of it.

Any ideas why?

The App:

```
app.js

require('dotenv').config()
const config = require('./utils/config')
const express = require('express')
require('express-async-errors')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan');
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const blogsRouter = require('./controllers/blogs')
const usersRouter = require('./controllers/users')
const loginRouter = require('./controllers/login')

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

app.use(middleware.tokenExtractor)

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static("build"))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/blogs', blogsRouter)
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter)
app.use('/api/login', loginRouter)

app.use(middleware.errorHandler)
app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)

app.use(morgan(':method :url :body'));

module.exports = app
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const app = require('./app')
const http = require('http')
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const config = require('./utils/config')

const server = http.createServer(app)

const PORT = process.env.PORT
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Server running on port ${config.PORT}`)
})
```

loginRouter

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const loginRouter = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/user')

loginRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const { username, password } = request.body

  const user = await User.findOne({ username })
  const passwordCorrect = user === null
    ? false
    : await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash)

  if (!(user && passwordCorrect)) {
    return response.status(401).json({
      error: 'invalid username or password'
    })
  }

  const userForToken = {
    username: user.username,
    id: user._id,
  }

  const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)

  response
    .status(200)
    .send({ token, username: user.username, name: user.name })
})

module.exports = loginRouter
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: "Heroku just seems to be throwing a 500 error just for the hell of it"—I assure you, this is not the case. Read your logs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the logs revealed what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

The loginRouter contains the following line necessary for generating a token:

```
const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)
```

Heroku does not know what process.env.SECRET is unless you tell it.

Go to your app page in Heroku ---> Settings ---> Reveal Config Vars

Click Add

Type SECRET into KEY and your value into VALUE

This then fixes the code.